# Mute and unmute Swift Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code written in my `MainMenuScene.swift` file to mute and unmute the background music

```
var mute: Bool = false

 override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     if nameOfTappedNode == "musicButton"{


            if mute {
                //This runs if the user wants music
                print("The button will now turn on music.")
                mute = false
                bgMusicPlayer?.volume = 1 //this is a .mp3 file
            } else {
                //This happens when the user doesn't want music
                print("the button will now turn off music.")
                mute = true
                bgMusicPlayer?.volume = 0
            }


}
```

My question is, how would I be able to mute every .wav and .mp3 files located in every scene within my game ? What is the most efficient way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By managing the `AVAudioPlayer`, or players, used to present them.

I keep a global array of players, and simply iterate that array when I want to affect all players in the game. For example:

```
var engineSound: AVAudioPlayer!
var shieldSound: AVAudioPlayer!
var photonSound1: AVAudioPlayer!
var photonSound2: AVAudioPlayer!
var photonSound3: AVAudioPlayer!
let arrayOfPlayers = [engineSound, shieldSound, photonSound1, photonSound2, photonSound3]

func fadeAllPlayers() {

    for player in arrayOfPlayers {

        player.volume = 0
    }
}
```

One of the advantages of an array of different players (as opposed to a single player) is that you can have multiple behaviors for different circumstances.

Comment: So what is the scope of  array and a function you mentioned ? I think that is important fact to include in the answer.

Comment: I've attempted to edit the answer to clarify that the array is global, but stack Overflow won't allow me to do so. Despite the religious resistance to global variables, in a media-heavy gaming application I think they are essential.

Comment: You may try again. Probably both of us were editing your question at the same time. Anyway, now we know that array is global ;)

Comment: Heh. Fixed. hope it's helpful.

Comment: Yeah... The notorious globals... But sometimes, if you use them sparingly :) they can be useful, obviously.

Comment: I'm curious what other answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Singleton implementation:

```
final class AudioManager {

    static let instance = AudioManager()
    //you should initialize it approp
    private var player = //... initialize with whatever player you use 

    private init() { }

    func play(){
        player.play()
    }    
}
```

Then wherever you need it (from every class):

```
 AudioManager.instance.play()
 AudioManager.instance.muteAll()
 AudioManager.instance.someOtherInstanceMethod()
```